# How do I add a 'CiviCRM ID' column to an activity report?

Tags: civireport

I want to add the CiviCRM ID to the csv report to allow for reloading the activities once some amends have been made? The problem is it is not an option anywhere within the create a report area.

Can anyone please help?

William

Answer (score 1):

The possible way to add CiviCRM ID (Internal Contact ID) is to use the find activities -> From search , find activities, select search criteria ( some Activities status are default on 'Activity Status'), - hit search, use action menu to export activities, Select fields to export ->continue, on the next page you can select individual fields to export (including Internal contact ID) and the activity fields you wish to export.